# IExplorerBrowser Performance Problems in Delphi XE2

Tags: performance, delphi, com, delphi-xe2

I'm trying to write a multi-panel, multi-tabbed file manager. I have been using IExplorerBrowser, but performance is terrible compared to Windows Explorer. Creating a single instance isn't too bad, but if I'm creating a 2 panel, 2 tabs per panel manager I have 4 IExplorerBrowser instances. Creation is very slow. Once created performance is acceptable. Are there any tricks to speeding it up or is this just one of the drawbacks of COM? My initialization code looks loosely like the following (exception handling and other unimportant details removed).

```
    TMyClass = class(TFrame)
      ...
      Panel1: TPanel;
      ...
    private
      ...
      FExplorerBrowser: IExplorerBrowser;
      FAdviseCookie: Cardinal;
      FSelectedPIDL: PItemIDList;
      procedure Initialize;
      ...
    protected
      ...
    public
      ...
    published
      ...
    end;

    procedure TMyClass.Initialize;
    var
      FS: TFolderSettings;
      R: TRect;
      HRes: HRESULT;
    begin
      HRes := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ExplorerBrowser, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IExplorerBrowser, FExplorerBrowser);

      if Succeeded(HRes) then
      begin
        FS.fFlags := 0;
        FS.ViewMode := FVM_DETAILS;

        R := Rect(0, Panel1.Height, ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
        HRes := FExplorerBrowser.Initialize(Handle, R, FS);

        if Succeeded(HRes) then
        begin
          HRes := FExplorerBrowser.SetOptions(EBO_SHOWFRAMES);

          if Succeeded(HRes) then
          begin
            HRes := FExplorerBrowser.Advise(Self as IExplorerBrowserEvents, FAdviseCookie);

            if Succeeded(HRes) then
            begin
              if FSelectedPIDL  nil then
                HRes := FExplorerBrowser.BrowseToIDList(FSelectedPIDL, 0);
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

Specifically the call to CoCreateInstance is the bottleneck. Any suggestions?

I'm using Delphi XE2 on Windows 7.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Do you have an antivirus running?  Is it slow the first time you create an object or only the following times?  What have you tried?  Did you run in other machines?

Comment: No antivirus. It's slow always. It's not significantly slow if you time a single instance, but compared to launching Windows Explorer it's very slow. Several hundred ms to create an instance, but when creating 4+ it takes a few seconds compared to much less time to create that many Windows Explorer instances by holding the Shift key and clicking on my pinned Explorer icon on the Win7 taskbar. It's too slow to be useful. I have only tried on my development machine because that's the target machine. If it runs quickly on others it's of no use to me. I doubt I'd see any change on others.